# How to attach a debugger of cheat engine to an application that compiled by VS2015 successfully?

Tags: debugging, timeout, cheat-engine

I am trying to attach a debugger of Cheat Engine to an application that wrote by me with C# VS2015. It always displays a message of debugger timeout, no matter what debugger mode I selected. How to attach a debugger of cheat engine successfully?

Error Message Capture:

https://postimg.cc/jDC1CYkC

https://i.postimg.cc/8zbgK1Rd/debugger-time-out.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download x64dbg and SyllaHide
2. Copy x64 of SyllaHide to x64dbg folder
3. Open x64dbg and attach the application you want.
4. Go to the "Dump1 view" of "CPU" tab. Press Ctrl+G, enter the address you want to set a breakpoint. And then move the cursor over the address and Right click select breakpoint, then select "Hardware, ACESS"

If the value is changed, the debugger will locate the induction and stop at there.